# Raising an exception for system library dependencies

Tags: ruby, exception, dependencies

I have a Ruby script that makes use of the wmctrl library and I wanted to ensure anyone using my CLI app has this as a dependency for all methods. What are the best practices to raising exceptions for 3rd party libraries as dependencies within a Ruby class?

The hack I've come up with is to issue a whatis system command and read the exit status code.

```
`which wmctrl`
unless $? == 0
  raise StandardError, "The wmctrl library is required." 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` will raise an error if it's not found and you can rescue it to specify the error message if you'd like:

```
begin
  require 'wmctrl'
rescue LoadError
  # error handling code here
end
```

Comment: Yup, this is how `multi_json` checks which `json` libraries are available as well: https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/blob/master/lib/multi_json.rb#L52

Comment: This does not seem to work for system libraries such as imagemagick.

Comment: if a user doesn't have a system library that most likely means they don't have a correct version of ruby installed right?